# Select a row from data table to show radio button value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have the data table and when i select a row from it, All value shows in input text field without radio button. here is the delegate function

```
$('#itb tbody').delegate('tr', 'click', function(){
        $("#SCC23_STATIONNAME").val($("td:eq(0)", this).text());
        $("#SCC23_DEPSTATION").val($("td:eq(1)", this).text());
        return false;
    });
```

If i have radio button as like

```
<tr><td>PROCEDURE TYPE  : </td>
                    <td><input type='radio' rel="2" name="SCC23_PROCTYPE" id="SCC23_PROCTYPE[]" value="ASSEMBLY">ASSEMBLY
                    <input type='radio' rel="2" name="SCC23_PROCTYPE" id="SCC23_PROCTYPE[]" value="SMT">SMT
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

How can i found the value of radio button when select a data table row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use prop function; something like `$("input[name=background][value='some value']").prop("checked",true);`

Check here.

https://jsfiddle.net/hvz8zq6j/5/

Comment: That works fine,,,,Thanks,,,,in my code it will be,,,                                            var proc = $("td:eq(3)", this).text();
$("input[name=SCC23_PROCTYPE]value="+proc+"]").prop("checked",true);

Answer (score 1):

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hvz8zq6j/1/

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function(e){

  var vals = $('input', this).map(function(){
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  alert(vals.join());
});
```

`$('input', this)` get all the input elements in the row

`.map(function(){return this.value;}).get();` get an array of their values